# Rails validations - cutom messages are not applied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a `Ride` model with `price` float field and validation of the precision. I want to display my own custom error message when the validation fails but it doesn't work.

According to [Rails Gudes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#message) "the :message option lets you specify the message that will be added to the errors collection when validation fails. When this option is not used, Active Record will use the respective default error message for each validation helper. The :message option accepts a String or Proc."

I do it exactly as in the example there and it does not work.

#### Rails guides

```
validates :age, numericality: { message: "%{value} seems wrong" }
```

#### My example

```
validates :price, numericality: { message: "Invalid price. Max 2 digits after period"}, format: { with: /\A\d{1,4}(.\d{0,2})?\z/ }
```

#### spec/models/ride_spec.rb

```
context 'with more than 2 digits after period' do
      let(:price) { 29.6786745 }

      it 'the price is invalid' do
        expect(subject.save).to be_falsy
        expect(subject).not_to be_persisted
        puts subject.errors.full_messages.last # "Price is invalid"
      end
    end
```

What am I doing wrong?

#### Update

This is what I've learned so far.
I have set the price to be empty in the test and it now shows the error message that I want.

```
context 'with more than 2 digits after period' do
      let(:price) { '' }

      it 'the price is invalid' do
        expect(subject.save).to be_falsy
        expect(subject).not_to be_persisted
        puts subject.errors.full_messages.last # "Price Invalid price. Max 2 digits after period"
      end
    end
```

Conslusion: it works for 'presence' validation, not for numericality validation, which is very confusing as the docs say clearly that you validate numericality, not presence. Am I right? Is this an error or deliberate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think where you are going wrong is expecting that `numericality` accepts a validation option `format`. Referring to the [active record guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#numericality) there is no option for `format`.

Seeing that you have called this `price` it seems you want to keep the precision to 2 decimal places so you can store the dollar value of something. The proper type for this is a decimal with `scale: 2`, or something I've had success with in the past is storing the `price` as an integer `price_in_cents`.

```
context 'with more than 2 digits after period' do
  let(:price) { 123.333 }

  it 'rounds to 2 decimal places' do
    expect(subject.save).to eq true
    expect(subject.reload.price).to eq 123.34
  end
end
```

Comment: I can't set precision on `Float` on DB level, I can set precision on `BigDecimal`, like so `precision: 10, scale: 2` but not on a Float. I need to have Float, though, because BigDecimals in Rails are returned as Strings in JSON API response and I need Floats on the front-end to do further calculations. So I need to validate the format in the model as a workaround.

Comment: I assume you are using the `price` to show the cost of something? If so I generally store the price as  `price_in_cents` and then convert to dollars where necessary.

Comment: Yes, exactly, to show the cost. So you don't validate the format, allow any value to be saved in DB and then just use `Money` gem to convert numbers like 23.4567934 to dollars, like $23.46?

Comment: Yes - use active record to save the value (decimal or int) then round at the last possible moment (generally when displaying the grand total).

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, there are two validations: format validation and numericality validation. I did not add message to format validation, so when it fails I get the standard message

```
validates :price, format: { with: /\A\d{1,4}(.\d{0,2})?\z/, message: 'Invalid price. Max 2 digits after period'}, numericality: { message: 'is not a number' }
```